# What is the difference between WKNavigationDelegate and WKUIDelegate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Can I use both of them in a project? 
I need to override WKUIDelegate's  CreateWebView method in order to open target=_blank links:

```
public override WKWebView CreateWebView(WKWebView webView, WKWebViewConfiguration configuration, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWindowFeatures windowFeatures)
    {
        var url = navigationAction.Request.Url;
        if (navigationAction.TargetFrame == null)
        {
            webView.LoadRequest(navigationAction.Request);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I use WKUIDelegate in a demo it works (opens target _blank). But in real project they used WKNavigationDelegate too. And applying WKUIDelegate CreateWebView doesn't work.

OnElementChange in the renderer is like this:

```
var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { };
            webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            // Set the delegate here
            webView = new WKWebView(this.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
            webView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
            webView.ScrollView.Bounces = true;
            webView.NavigationDelegate = new DisplayLinkWebViewDelegate();
            webView.UIDelegate = MyWkWebViewDelegate();
            SetNativeControl(webView);
```

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT it is helpful. But in my case somhow the CreateWebView method is not called. I think the problem is there.

Comment: Can you share your sample so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT you can find it here: https://github.com/muratsesen/Xamarin/tree/master

Comment: Where is your WKUIDelegate?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I added it to the repo.

Comment: Change  `webView.WeakUIDelegate = new MyWkWebViewDelegate();` to `webView.UIDelegate = new MyWkWebViewDelegate();`

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Doesn't worked.

Comment: You didn't provide the full sample , I create the demo with WKWebviewRenderer and it works fine .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Everything you wrote was correct. The problem is from the view part which was not under my control.

Answer (score 4):

**WKNavigationDelegate** :  It helps you implement custom behaviors that are triggered during a web view's process of accepting, loading, and completing a navigation request.

And the **WKUIDelegate** class provides methods for presenting native user interface elements on behalf of a webpage.

The **webpage** here is not the webview ,but the html which been loaded on webview.

As we can see in following image

[image]

The method in **WKUIDelegate** are all associated with JS.

For more details about the two protocols you can check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate?language=objc

and

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate?language=objc

if you want to do something when the webview finished loading, you can implement the method **DidFinishNavigation** in **WKNavigationDelegate** .

```
public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
{
  if(!webView.IsLoading)
  {
     // do some thing you want
  }
}
```